# annidate variable undefined - angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a annidate variable like that.

```
  $scope.a = { b: {c : 1} };
  var test = $scope.a.b.c;
      // test == 1
  $scope.a = {}
  var test = $scope.a.b.c;
      // ERROR
```

I want test variable will be null or undefined.

How can I fill test variable without error?

some advice?

I'm looking for a smart way

not only

```
if(angular.isDefinied($scope.a) && angular.isDefinied($scope.a.b) && angular.isDefinied($scope.a.b.c))
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: How can I fill test variable without error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like that:

```
var test = ($scope.a && $scope.a.b && $scope.a.b.c) ? $scope.a.b.c : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not defined the value before using it, then definitely, it will throw an error. You must define or you must check whether it is defined or not. Otherwise you can't resolve the error. `var test` will get a value only if there is no error. Now, its up to you to decide and use a smart way

```
var test = $scope.a?((typeof($scope.a.b)=="object" && $scope.a.b.c)?$scope.a.b.c:(typeof($scope.a)=="object" && $scope.a.b)?$scope.a.b:null):null
```

Comment: Humhum... From the question: "**I'm looking for a smart way**".

Comment: Should I delete my answer as you said, it is wrong or now, it is not a better solution?